# Retain singleton instance after thrown exception

Tags: android, android-activity, exception, singleton

I have created an Android application that uses a singleton to hold its state. The class is instantiated when the application starts.

The application does make extensive use of fragments but is not a single Activity application.

The problem occurs when an activity crashes for some (any) reason.

Normally, Android closes the activity bringing to the foreground the previous one that was active. Since the previous activity also used the singleton somehow, it needs data from it to resume (for example). The thing is that the singleton is no longer available while the previous activity is running in a new Application Context forcing the Singleton to re-instantiate itself with no data of course.

One way to surpass this problem seems to be storing the state (serialized or not) in a file or the database but that means too many read writes on pretty much every other user activity which should be avoided. Apart from UX, this solution might lead to inconsistent or erroneous data from faulty or untimely synchronisations.

I would like to hear your input on the matter.
Cheers!

Here is the Singleton instantiation method.

```
final public class Data {
    private static Data INSTANCE = new Data();

    private Data() {}

    public static Data getInstance() { 
        return INSTANCE; 
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate your singleton? Post some code.

Comment: can't you use sharedpreferences instead ?

Comment: @localhost there you go.

Comment: @Poutrathor the data needed to be saved are a lot so I wouldn't like the idea. but as a last resort it will be something like that...

Comment: To those who voted down, please be so kind and elaborate on your decision to do so. If something is wrong in the question, I'd be happy to fix it (and learn from the procedure)

Comment: your question is not very good because 1) it is general and quite open 'not suited to SO format' 2) persistency of data between activities is a beat-up subject with lot of documentation/blogs/custom solution and more

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your singleton as static on a root activity it should be saved. We used static varaibles linked to a baseline activty from which every activity dereives.

Antoher solution might be to use sharedpreferences.

It is nice to worry about performance but if you have many fragments and few activities, it would be the fragment that will cause the lion share of teh workload

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. It's gonna be destroyed at the very last stage.

2) If your data is not structured - you can keep it in SharedPreferences (as a String mapped with JSON for example)

3) If your data is structured - you should store it in DB (or better ContentProvider)